# Immutable objects when working with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, autofac

I'm fairly new to oop and programming in general, but one thing that i don't understand if when working with relational databases like in EF core you should have immutable objects or not.
If i set properties with private setters, so that i can only assign values when creating these objects, how can I change their state?
Do i create a new empty objects and then copy every single properties that needs to stay the same and update only some of them with `myObject.property = updatedValue`?
Do i use a factory to instanciate that object with the correct values?
Isn't this violating oop principles by having public setters?

I have encounter this problem for example when having a server and a client that exchange data and the client do somework on this data. When the data returns, with a dto class, i still need to update the related data that is saved in the database.

Comment: A private setter doesn't mean a new value can never be set, it just means that nothing outside the class can reach in and set it. Code inside the class is still able to set a new value. Perhaps you're mixing it up with `readonly` things, which can only be set once

Comment: well if you want to have immutable objects, private fields should be readonly right?

Comment: EF Core tracks objects connected to the database so it can send updates - immutable objects don't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking immutable objects, then no you will not update their values, and you will have to create a whole new instance if that object changes, that is what makes them immutable. But if you are trying to encapsulate an entity that can change state, and would like to change the values of that entity, then you would typically have command methods on that object that will change the values of the properties to provide the encapsulation, I believe you are shooting for.

In the past when I have went a similar route using an ORM, I had data entities (classes) at the data layer that had public getters and setters, and the ORM would instantiate the objects and populate them without issue, then my repository would map them to the business layer classes that had private setters. I believe I used automapper to do this, and it didn't have a problem mapping with the private setters.

Then from a UI interaction perspective, to update the models, the business entities would have specific command methods rather than just an overarching "update" method. Things like "UpdateAddress", "makePayment", and such. These methods would update the appropriate private variables of the class and filter down into the data entities and then to the database.

I do think a lot of this can be overkill depending on what you are working on, a lot of applications are mostly CRUD applications, and don't require a lot of business rules. In that case I personally wouldn't worry about private setters and whatnot, unless it makes sense for you.

Answer (score 7):

EF Core does support immutability, more specifically it can utilize the constructors of your entities. This enables you to create purely immutable properties for your entities (only getters, which generate readonly backing fields), or even the whole entity can be immutable.

Some points to consider:

- EF by default excludes/ignores all the properties with getters only. It assumes they are calculated properties. For those properties, we should explicitly configure EF to include them in the model.
- If we have included readonly properties in the model, EF will require a constructor (it may be marked as private) with matching parameters for these properties. You must have a constructor which accepts parameters only for these properties, not including the mutable ones.
- The constructor parameters should be named exactly as the properties. Excluding the first character, the naming is case-sensitive. For a given FirstName property, you may define the parameter as FirstName or firstName, but not as firstname. This is a common mistake.
- If you have defined immutable owned types (e.g., value objects) as part of the entity, you might be compelled to add them as constructor parameters. Doing so will be an incorrect configuration, and you’ll face runtime exceptions. EF Core creates instances of these objects separately and has a different internal mechanism of mapping these objects to the entity.

I have elaborated in more detail in this [blog post](https://fiseni.com/posts/immutable-entities-in-ef-core/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it has been very helpfull.

Comment: You're welcome. Here is a sample application. https://github.com/fiseni/ImmutabilitySample

Comment: Those are a lot of requirements in order to achieve immutability. Why would you want to go trough all the trouble? What would be like the big pro, in doing this?

Comment: Encapsulation? Consistent state?

Would I do this in every project? Certainly not. If you have a small project with few entities, or if you're doing microservices, then it's just not worth it.

On the other hand, if you have a relatively large project, you would like to design it better to minimize the technical debt as much as possible. You write this once, and you're sure you'll never end up in a corrupted state. Refactoring becomes way smoother and easier in the future.